# Django translation reverse

Tags: python, django, gettext

Is it possible to get msgid from msgstr?

Suppose I have

```
msgid "Table"
msgstr "Tisch"
```

If active language is German is there any function to execute `inverse_ugettext('Tisch') -> Table`?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Django's translation uses GNU gettext, and the python implementation is in the standard library. There's no _reverse_ functionality as far as I can find. https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gnu-gettext-api

Comment: Most likely you're having a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here. What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not *trivially* possible. At least not with the django i18n implementation (which uses python's gettext).

If you **really** need this, you'll have to manually implement it somehow ([the gettext source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b204540be475922c5cb2ee2adc7caa3dadcca33c/Lib/gettext.py) might be a useful starting place).

If speed is not critical here (eg: it's a very infrequent operation), you might want to parse the `.po` files, which are a lot simpler to parse, and find the reverse there.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.