# Reverse Language Translation in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API using Django Rest Framework that needs to support multiple languages, we're trying to use the Django translation framework, and using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305400/django-translating-choice-fields) I've decided how to implement translatable choicefields. However my issue is for the reverse case.

Say I have a model like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Payment(models.Model):
    OPEN = 0
    CLOSED = 1
    BALANCE = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (OPEN, _('open')),
        (CLOSED, _('closed')),
        (BALANCE, _('balance')),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=OPEN, verbose_name=_("Status"))
```

This works fine for returning the information to the user, we use the stored status value and translate it before returning. However, I also want the user to be able to POST a new payment object using any language. So if the user wants to create an open transaction, they can send `{'status':'open'}` but they can also send it in Spanish as `{'status':'abierto'}`. Is there a way to handle this automatically?

Basically I want to get the reverse of the ugettext_lazy function.

Comment: what is the point of posting `abierto` instead of `open` for a choice field? (I mean it's just the post API don't make it unecessarily  complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django translation reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058679/django-translation-reverse)

Comment: I asked the same question, unfortunately I don't get the final say in what we need to support. :) It looks like there isn't a simple built in way to do this from your other question.

Comment: Having your api accept multiple languages in this way seems completely bonkers to me. I hope the client pays by the hour, because this kind of "feature" would add a huge amount of extra work for testing and QA.

Comment: Since `status` is an IntegerField, you would typically post an integer in the api as well. If you want the translated choices, you can submit an `OPTIONS` request to the api endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ugettext_noop` instead `ugettext_lazy`.